# Request with proxy getting blocked from web server but not on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, httparty

I am trying to make a request to a website with a proxy using [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) like so:

```
def self.fetch_page_with_html_response(url, proxy_id)

    proxy = Proxy.find(proxy_id)

    request_options = {
        http_proxyaddr: proxy.url, http_proxyport: proxy.port, http_proxyuser: proxy.username, http_proxypass: proxy.password,
        headers: {"User-Agent" => proxy.user_agent}
    }

    response = HTTParty.get(url, request_options)

    response
end
```

On certain websites my requests either hangs or returns an error page where the website is blocking me from fetching the page.

When i use these same proxy settings in my Chrome browser using an extension like [SwitchyOmega](http://ttps://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif) the requests goes through fine and the page loads.

Is there any reason why the request would be getting blocked from my web server but not through my browser?

I even tested using the same user agent and providing the same exact headers my browser is sending.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some reasons in your case.

1. Can you check if proxy works correctly?
   Please send get request to https://api.ipify.org/ using your proxy in code.
   If it returns correct ip address, then the proxy works.
2. Please disable javascript run in chrome settings. Then browse the website via proxy.
   And check if website load correctly.
   Because some websites render html and css using javascript.

Please feel free to reply me if you still need help.